# ASP.NET MVC 4 How to update model and rerender parital view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to click a button and have an object added to a list in my model. It should add a new object each time the button is clicked I also have a partial view that renders based on the number of objects in this list that also needs to be updated when this occurs.  I know I need to use ajax but it's not something I'm very familiar with.

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult NewScheduleRequest()
    {
        var srm = new NewScheduleRequestModel();
        srm.Request = new ResourceRequest();
        srm.Request.ResourceRequestScheds.Add(new ResourceRequestSched(){StartDateRequested = DateTime.Today, EndDateRequested = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)});
        return PartialView("NewScheduleRequestView", srm);
    }
```

And the html in question:

```
<div id="timeFrames">
        @Html.Partial("_TimeframePartial", Model)
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" value="Add Timeframe" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAddTimeframe" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My partial view:

```
@model Application.Models.NewScheduleRequestModel

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Request.ResourceRequestScheds.Count; i++)
{

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="startDialog">Start</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Request.ResourceRequestScheds[i].StartDateRequested, "dateTextBox")
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="endDialog">End</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Request.ResourceRequestScheds[i].EndDateRequested, "dateTextBox")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Mon</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Request.ResourceRequestScheds[i].MonHoursRequested, Model.Hours, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Tues</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Request.ResourceRequestScheds[i].TuesHoursRequested, Model.Hours, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Wed</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Request.ResourceRequestScheds[i].WedHoursRequested, Model.Hours, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Thurs</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Request.ResourceRequestScheds[i].ThursHoursRequested, Model.Hours, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Fri</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Request.ResourceRequestScheds[i].FriHoursRequested, Model.Hours, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />

}
```

and here is the start of my ajax. This is what I'm not sure how to do or even how to really start:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAddTimeframe").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
            });
        });
    });
```

Am I approaching this correctly or do I need to rethink?  If I'm on the right track it'd be great if someone could help figure out what I need to do from here.

Comment: whats your _TimeframePartial partial content?

Comment: added the partial view content

Comment: You can use `$.get('@Url.Action("NewScheduleRequest", "YourControllerName")', function(data) { $('#timeFrames').append(data); })`. However if your adding multiple items, then your never going to be able to post back and bind to a collection (the controls will not be correctly named with indexers) so it might be a bit pointless.